# Hide One Section Wordpress Login Page

Tags: css, wordpress, authentication, customization, wordpress-login

I am looking to hide the LinkedIn login button on the main login page of my site: http://takeoff.im/wp-admin

I've tried:

```
#loginform p:nth-child(3) {display: none !important;}
```

but that does not seem to be working

Comment: It works when I insert the CSS into the head of the page.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I got it to work when I created a new style sheet just for that page!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like wherever you're adding your CSS, the login administrator page is not picking up the actual styles. Since the login page uses an automatically generated stylesheet, in your case the URL of the generated styles is [**HERE**](http://takeoff.im/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,buttons,forms,l10n,login&ver=4.9.5)

There's some nice documentation here on [**THIS**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) page which talks about customizing the login page. One very important thing to note from the documentation on the previous link, is  the [`login_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts) hook which you can utilize to add in your own custom stylesheet for editing the said page.